# Subtracting registers with an LEA instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, pointer-arithmetic, addressing-mode

Does the LEA instruction support negative displacement?

```
mov rax, 1
lea rsi, [rsp - rax]
```

When I use the above code in my asm file I got the error:

```
$ nasm -f macho64 test.asm
$ error: invalid effective address
```

I Know that we can do pointer arithmetic like this in C:

```
void foo(char *a, size_t b) {
    *(a - b) = 1;
}
```

then I assume that:

```
lea rsi, [rsp - rax]
```

will work.

And I also try to see what the GCC compiler do by using:

```
$ gcc -S foo.c // foo.c has the function foo(above) in it
```

but my asm knowleage is not enough for me the understand the asm output
from the GCC compiler.

Can anyone explain why:

```
lea rsi, [rsp - rax]    ;; invalid effective address
```

does not work. And I'm using these to achieve the samething:

```
;; assume rax has some positive number
neg rax    
lea rsi, [rsp + rax]
neg rax
```

or

```
sub rsp, rax
mov rsi, rsp
add rsp, rax
```

What is a more standard way of doing it?

I'm using NASM version 2.11.08 compiled on Nov 26 2015 on MAC OSX 10.11

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Because the CPU doesn't support such kind of operation?

Comment: How about `mov rsi, rsp \ sub rsi, rax`

Comment: @MikeCAT simply enough, you can make this as answers. Thank you!

Comment: @harold that looks better, thank you!

Comment: ARM addressing modes can add or subtract the index register, but [x86 can only add (with an optional scale factor)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34058400/224132).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `lea` instruction doesn't care about the sign of the displacement. But you do need to always **add** the components together.

```
mov rax, -1
lea rsi, [rsp + rax]
```

Remember subtracting 1 is the same as adding -1.